# How to limit the number of session or devices for the one user to login simultaneously using B2C custom policies?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is any chance to check if the user already login using B2C and logout from the first session when the user try to login to another session or other device?

Basically it might be useful to prevent security issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly configure B2C to logout the user from first session when he/she tries to login to another session or other device.

As of now, best you can do in order to prevent security issues related to sessions is by configuring Identity Protection with B2C. With Identity protection, you can detect risks based on:

Risk detection type Description

- **Atypical travel:** Sign-in from an atypical location based on the user's recent sign-ins.
- **Anonymous IP address:** Sign-in from an anonymous IP address (for example: Tor browser, anonymizer VPNs).
- **Malware linked IP address:** Sign-in from a malware linked IP address.
- **Unfamiliar sign-in properties:** Sign-in with properties we've not seen recently for the given user.
- **Admin confirmed user compromised:** An admin has indicated that a user was compromised.
- **Password spray:** Sign-in through a password spray attack.
- **Azure AD threat intelligence:** Microsoft's internal and external threat intelligence sources have identified a known attack pattern.

**Read More:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-protection-investigate-risk?pivots=b2c-user-flow
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-identity-protection-overview